# Use query vars in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am adding a custom php code in wordpress website,where I have links with parameters; And I can not access those parameters using **GET** method instead using **query vars**.And I am having problem on accessing those parameters from my custom php code.

I have added the below function in functions.php

```
function my_query_vars( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "q";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_query_vars' );
```

and to access query vars in my custom php code

```
$my_var = get_query_var( 'q' );
echo'<a href="'.esc_url( add_query_arg( 'q', $my_var ) ).'">My Link</a>';
```

I want to print the value of parameter from the URL after clicking the link,so how can I go?

Comment: Didn't `$my_var = get_query_var( 'q' );` get the value of the parameter already? What is the problem with printing the value?

Comment: It's getting the value,but when clicked that link doesn't retrieve data based on the value of that parameter instead,it's redirecting to posts archive page

Comment: What do you want to show on the link?

Comment: **https://example.com/?q=7018** I want to get that value from URL parameter and use in query retrieving data in database

Comment: Needs more clarification. Do you want to show a post with extra retrieved data? Or do you want to show list of posts with extra specification?